# Javascript file make css not to work in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

When i include the js file in base.html `<script src="static/assets/js/functions.js"></script>` the CSS stops working entirely but when i remove the JS file or comment it out the CSS start loading and rendering well. I even tried putting the whole js code manually into the base.html but it still doesnt work i dont really know what to do right now.

The JS and CSS Files are located in a static folder in root directly and i'm sure there is not typo or anything not well arranged

Comment: Why not use the `{% static %}` tag to generate the correct path, like you do for all your other JS and CSS?

Comment: @IainShelvington please where should i use the  {% static %}? in my base.html?? i get this error when i use it in base.html top    TemplateSyntaxError at /
'static' takes at least one argument (path to file)

Comment: Copy how you used the tag for every other JS file: `<script src="{% static 'assets/js/functions.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: @IainShelvington i did it already in my base.html but it still doesn't work, i appreciate your time

Comment: Don't know if it's just for showcasing, but I can't see the <body> tag anywhere!?

Comment: @finethen thanks for your response, but the body tag is added above, i didn't just include it

Comment: better use `src="/static/...` with `/` before `static` - instead of `src="static/...`

Comment: @furas thanks for you response, you know it's django and i'm trying to include the css from another file in a static folder so if i use src="/static/... is it gonna work?

Comment: with `/` at the beginning it is absolute path. without `/` at the beginnning it is relative path which may search file in wrong place.

Comment: if you use `{% static ...%}` then you have to use `path` without `static` at the beginning because it will add it automatically. `{% static 'assets/js/functions.js' %}` instead of `{% static 'static/assets/js/functions.js' %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly  know what the issue was but when i added `<base href="{% static '/' %}">` it started working just fine